# Java eclipse run android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

im starting developing android applications and i learned from a Hello World tutorial. but when im running it this comes to the screen

Launch configuration ANSIBuffer references non-existing project Basic.

Please, help me and tell how i can run a android application.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend downloading the official adt (android development tools) plugin for eclipse.  You can find instructions on how to do that here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html you need to make sure that you have the most recent version of android sdk installed before you do that.  Instructions on how to install that are here (this includes a eclipse tutorial): http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html
I believe that that is all you need.  Just ask if you need more help!

Answer (score 0):

I did a guide once for a course, but it is in spanish:

http://otfusion.org/android/ (look for day 2)

But basically the guide is this:

1. Download JDK from here: [Java SE - Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
2. Download Android SDK (.zip format, just unzip it in C:\android-sdk or if you are in *nix /home/user/android-sdk) from here: [Android SDK - Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
3. Start ~android-sdk/tools/android and download your desired android target (eclair, donut, honeycomb, etc)
4. Download Eclipse for **Java Developers*** (as far I know, the latest eclipse WORKS on my notebook) from here: [Eclipse - Indigo](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigor)
5. Install eclipse in **a readable/writable location** like */home/user/bin* or /opt/eclipse but give permission to the file - *chown -r user:users /opt/eclipse* (in Windows you must not have problems) otherwhise you will have problems.
6. Install ADT Plugin just add this site in Eclipse "Add Software" option (Help menu) https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
7. Restart Eclipse
8. Start one AVD and initiate your project using the Run button (As Android project) or whatever hotkey you use.

**Also, *[Installing guide from developer.android.com Troubleshooting](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#troubleshooting)***

***Note:** Classic didn't work for me